# Почему в C++ возникает ошибка "неизвестный спецификатор переопределения" с классом string?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-c++

Создал класс `teacher` в `C++`. Создал поля класса и конструктор. В конструкторе, естественно, присваиваю полям класса данные, поступившие в конструктор. Содержимое файла `teacher.h`:

```
class teacher{
public:
    string surname;
    string name;
    string patronymic;
    bool doctor;
    int dolzhnost;
    int stazh;

    teacher(string surname_, string name_, string patronymic_, bool doctor_, int dolzhnost_, int stazh_) {
        surname = surname_;
        name = name_;
        patronymic = patronymic_;
        doctor = doctor_;
        dolzhnost = dolzhnost_;
        stazh = stazh_;
    }
};
```

Содержимое файла `main.cpp`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include "teacher.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    teacher informatics = teacher("Иванов", "Иван", "Иванович", true, 1, 5);
}
```

Компилирую данную программу и получаю от С++ ошибки:

```
surname: неизвестный спецификатор переопределения
name: неизвестный спецификатор переопределения
patronymic: неизвестный спецификатор переопределения
```

Comment: Компилятор не знает, что такое `string`. Это приводит к наведенным ошибкам, которые вы и видите. Стандартный класс называется `std::string`, а не `string`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Поменяйте местами эти две строки:

```
#include "teacher.h"
using namespace std;
```

А еще лучше - в заголовочных файлах указывайте полностью квалифицированные имена, с указанием пространства имен - типа `std::string`.